# Silverstripe 4 - Add TagField in Inline GridField

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I want to add a TagField to the Inline Fields of GridField. The GridField manages Images.

The problem is when I add a Tag and hit save an error comes:

`[Emergency] Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Object->__call(): the method 'Tags' does not exist on '(**ClassWhichHasGridField**)'`

It should check for Tags() on the $record and not on the Page where the GridField is located.

```php
$gc->set([
    'noEdit',
    'inline' => [
        'edit',
        'fields' => [
            'Tags' => [
                'title' => 'Tags',
                'callback' => function($record, $column, $grid) {
                    TagField::create('Tags', 'Tags', Tag::get(), $record->Tags());
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Can you share the code for "ClassWhichHasGridField" please?

Comment: Hi. You are more likely to get an answer if you describe what you've tried to do looking for resource to fix the problem.

Comment: Is just a simple Class which extends from Page with a GridField in the getCMSFields Function. Do you have a guess what can solve the problem?